# Rviz not displaying anything

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner.
This is the URDF file code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="pan_tilt">

  <link name="base_link">

    <visual>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.01" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="yellow">
        <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.03" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
    <mass value="1"/>
    <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="pan_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="pan_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.1"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit effort="300" velocity="0.1" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14"/>
    <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="pan_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.4" radius="0.04"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.09"/>
      <material name="red">
        <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.4" radius="0.06"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.09"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
    <mass value="1"/>
    <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="tilt_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="pan_link"/>
    <child link="tilt_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.2"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit effort="300" velocity="0.1" lower="-4.64" upper="-1.5"/>
    <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="tilt_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.4" radius="0.04"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 1.5 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="green">
        <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.4" radius="0.06"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 1.5 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
    <mass value="1"/>
    <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>

  </link>


</robot>
```

Below is the launch file code

```
<launch>

    <arg name="model" />

        
        <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg)/urdf/seven_dof_arm.xacro" />

        
       
        <param name="use_gui" value="true"/>

        
        <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />


        
        <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
    
            

        <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />

</launch>
```

---

When I launch the launch file, It launches the Rviz but it doesn't display the model in it.
It's basically empty.
What could I be doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285051/rviz-not-displaying-anything/) by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-03-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-03-11**:
Did you add an RobotModel-Widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

check if your fixed frame in rviz is defined

---

Originally posted by [nmssilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/34098/nmssilva/) with karma: 16 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0